# not sure how to add up QP in total

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades2
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    
    int NUMBER_OF_COURSES = 5;
    int totalQualityPoints;
    double GPA; // Grade Point Average
    int QP = 0; // only need to store quality points
    String courseGrade;
    int[] courseNumber ={5};
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    
    for (int n = 1; n<=5; n++) 
    {
      System.out.print( "Enter Class "+n+" grade : " );
      courseGrade = in.next();
      
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "A" ) )
        System.out.println( "Outstanding" );
      QP += 4;
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "B" ) )
        System.out.println( "Above average" );
      QP += 3;
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "C" ) )
        System.out.println( "Average" );
      QP += 2;
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "D" ) )
        System.out.println( "Below average" );
      QP += 1;
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "F" ) )
        System.out.println( "Try again" );
      QP += 0;
    }
    
    
    System.out.println(QP);
    
  }
}
```

I need the QP to add up in total but so far I've gotten 50 with my methods. I've tried putting an [courseNumber] next to the QP but I received array required, but int found and int[] cannot be converted to int errors

Comment: Maybe you are missing curly braces when using `if` statements e.g. `if ( courseGrade.equals( "A" ) ) {
        System.out.println( "Outstanding" );
      QP += 4; }`

Comment: Ah silly me :') thankyou for help, it worked well